# Login to the WAMP mysql console

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

After I went to phpMyAdmin to create new user.

```
Username: ken
Hostname: localhost
Password: 123456
Checked Global Privilege
```

When I start the MySQL console, it said that I need to enter the password.  I pressed `[ENTER]` and it seem I have login to root. I haven't create password for root yet, Do I have to create a password for root? (I know it kinda dumb question, but I just want be crystal clear and simple answer)

Also, If I wanted to login to my newly created user, how do I do it?
I tried:

```
mysql> mysql -h localhost -u ken -p
->exit
```

Nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL Console menu item in WAMPServer is setup to use the `root` account.

As the `root` account comes out of the box with no password set, then the correct thing to do is to just hit enter when the mysql processor asks for a password.

If you set a password on the MYSQL `root` account then when the MYSQL Console asks for a password you can use the newly created password.

If you want to login to MYSQL using a different user account, then it is simpler to use a command window and CD into the mysql folder and run the mysql.exe processor from there like

```
> cd \wamp\bin\mysql\mysql{version}\mysql
mysql -uken -p
```

I personally use a little batch file, that I store in a folder that is already on the windows PATH, ***never add a wamp folder to the windows PATH as this will mess you up when/if you ever install more than one version of MYSQL in your WAMPServer!***

mysqlpath.bat

```
echo off

if %1.==. GOTO ERROR

PATH=%PATH%;c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql%1\bin
echo
echo -----------------------------------------------
mysql -V
echo -----------------------------------------------
echo
GOTO EndPHP

:ERROR
echo -----------------------------------------------
echo Parameter 1 should be something like 5.4.13 to use mysql5.4.13
echo -----------------------------------------------
:EndPHP
```

Then you run it like

```
>mysqlpath 5.7.10
```

and it sets that path up just for the duration of the command windows life.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to logout of your current and then login with your new user:

For exiting just type:

```sh
> exit;
```

Then login with your new user:

```sh
$ mysql -u <username> -p
```

### Keep in mind that:

**By default** mysql logic try with host localhost, otherwise if your server it's in another host just add the flag `-h <your-hostname>` at the end of your Shell request.

**By default** also, mysql try with port 3306, otherwise if your mysql's server port it's in another port just add `--port=3333` at the end of your Shell request.

Keep in mind that if you aren't enable to run console interface of mysql you can use a **Environment PATH** for executing mysql otherwise you must edit your comand... changing mysql by the path to the wamp mysql bin location.

Let's supose you have mysql in this location: **C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\bin**, then, your comand will be:

```sh
D:\wamp2\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\bin\mysql.exe -u <username> -p
```

And that's it. If you have any issue please let me know, I will gladly help.

Resources:
[How to manage MySQL databases and users from the command line](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/managing-mysql-databases-and-users-from-the-command-line)